# android playing two songs problem

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have a problem playing audio files. when i entered two words like 'hi tom', only last word is playing. But in my log cat it seems to pass first word song. is my code wrong ? or is there any solution to here first song and then here second song? any solution is ok for me for example it can be lag between these songs. thanks.
i saw musicdroid code also about nextsong. but i am new to android and i couldnt integrate my code.[musicdroid](http://r00tsecurity.org/forums/topic/12127-musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii/)

```
public  void function (String[][] word)
{

try{    
for (int j=0;j<word.length;j++)
{
    for(int i=0;i<word[j].length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("word:"+word[j][i]);
        if(word[j][i].equals("empty")==false)     
        {
        mediaPlayer.reset();        
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/voice/"+word[j][i]+".ogg");
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        System.out.println(word[j][i]+"-");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("end");

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("error:"+e.getMessage());
}
}
```

here its my log cat. it seems to take first voice but not play.

```
04-04 09:58:18.934: INFO/System.out(363):word:hi

04-04 09:58:18.944: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('/sdcard/voice/hi.ogg')

04-04 09:58:19.024: DEBUG/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12

04-04 09:58:19.024: INFO/System.out(363): hi-

04-04 09:58:19.024: INFO/System.out(363): word:tom
04-04 09:58:19.034: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('/sdcard/voice/tom.ogg')

04-04 09:58:19.114: DEBUG/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12

04-04 09:58:19.124: INFO/System.out(363): tom-

04-04 09:58:19.124: INFO/System.out(363): end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wait for the first sound to finish before you play the next one.
Try adding a listener to the mediaplayer, and play the second word after the first one finishes.

Check out the setOnCompletionListener.

Also read the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Thank you for your answering. In listener, will i put extra any code like mediaPlayer.release();  or just leave it ?